# Routes in play2: How to match a part of the url

Tags: routes, playframework-2.0

There are some urls like:

```
http://localhost:9000/images/111111.jpg
http://localhost:9000/images/222222.png
http://localhost:9000/images/333333.gif
```

They will be mapped to a method:

```
def showImage(id: String) = Action {
    val image = Image.findById(id).get
    Ok.sendFile(new File(image.path)
}
```

Note that the `id` is the only part of filename showed in url: `111111`, `222222`, `333333`

So I write a mapping in routes:

```
GET  /images/$id<\w+>.*          controllers.Images.showImage(id)
```

In the part `$id<\w+>.*`, `id` is matching the id, and `.*` match the suffix which will be ignored.

But the syntax is incorrect, the error message is:

```
Identifier expected
```

How to fix it?

Comment: They syntax for routes in Play 2 is /images/:id not $id.

Comment: No, I'm using the regex syntax

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It’s not currently possible to do that with Play 2. As a workaround you can process your argument in the controller action:

```
GET    /images/:id       controllers.Images.showImage(id)
```

```
def showImage(idWithExt: String) = Action {
  val id = idWithExt.takeWhile(_ != '.')
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is works, but not clear. I will submit a request for it

Comment: Ah, that's disappointing. @Freewind, was there any feedback on your request?